# Assign specific roles based on AD groups using AZ cli

Tags: bash, azure

I'm trying to assign roles in Azure based on existing AD groups. Need to use bash script for this task. For a given AD group, I've pre-defined set of roles. Looking for an efficient and simple way of doing this.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Ram

Comment: You may use az cli for your task. Is it sufficient?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-cli

Comment: @AndriyBilous - Thanks Andriy. Yes, am planning to use az cli for this. Since I've many AD groups, am trying to script it using bash. I'm trying with case statements. Trying to see if there is any efficient and simple approach in dealing this.